# Web Browser with HTTPS in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, document

I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 application, I am trying to launch document using Launcher but getting an error.My URI is "HTTPS". See my code below:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xx"));
```

See my attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it only happens in https? Is the certificate valid and date/time of phone correct?

Comment: @the_nuts yes, date/time of phone is correct, I do not know about certificate. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @the_nuts how to proceed with certificate and how to install?

Comment: Sorry I never done it, I always pass through my http site even for apis like YouTube, because if their phone date is wrong it wouldn't work, anyway you could read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn643705.aspx